# "The odor of strong rum made a greasy pass through the room."

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation

I found the sentence as a [ldoce](http://www.ldoceonline.com) sample sentence for "odor".

> The odor of strong rum made a greasy pass through the room.

"*... made a greasy pass through the room*".

What does the writer mean? The odor made the greasy pass?

Comment: Nice evocation. What's it from?

Comment: @Kit: Found the sentence in "Example Bank" of Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a strange phrase to use for an example.  It comes from *Swimming in the Volcano*
 By Bob Shacochis.  It's not a commonly used phrase at all.

I'd hazard that it means that the smell of alcohol wafted through the room.  I'd picture that room as hot, sweaty, dirty, dim, and *greasy*.  Given the [scene](http://books.google.com/books?id=OKdIHg_aM5EC&pg=PA196&dq=%E2%80%9CThe+odor+of+strong+rum+made+a+greasy+pass+through+the+room.%E2%80%9D&hl=en&ei=CSPxTfOtHoragQf168yoBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CThe%20odor%20of%20strong%20rum%20made%20a%20greasy%20pass%20through%20the%20room.%E2%80%9D&f=false) in which it occurs, this seems to be accurate.

So yes, I think the odor made the pass, and it was the environment that made it a greasy pass.  This is a very literary phrasing though.  I doubt you'd see it often.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example of the rhetorical figure known as *[catachresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis)*, which is "an extravagant, implied metaphor using words in an alien or unusual way."

Example:

> - I will speak daggers to her. — *Hamlet*

NOAD calls it "the use of a word in a way that is not correct," but that's far from the whole of it. A catachresis can be a mistake or an intentional figure of speech. That is, if it's good, you call it intentional; if not, a mistake. ;=) Be careful, though. Using this device is akin to playing a violin: if you're not an absolute master, it just sounds awful.